# Is there any way to make ycm's(Youcompleteme) diagnostics for python more convenient in vi

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, language-server-protocol, syntastic, youcompleteme

Ycm build-in in Jedi doesn't support diagnostics. I tried some ways, like YCM's LSP and Syntastics, but various problems appear when using other plugins.

For ycm, lsp, and pyright, it works well except hover. When I toggle on semantic completion and select words, a docstring displays in a popup with no problem. Only hover( `<plug>(YCMHover)` )
vimrc

```
...
let g:ycm_language_server += [
            \   {
            \       'name': 'pyright',
            \       'filetypes': [ 'python' ],
            \       'cmdline': [ 'node', substitute(system('which pyright-langserver'), '\n', '', ''), '--stdio' ],
            \   },
            \ ]
...
```

global_extra_conf.py

```py
def Settings(**kwargs):
    return {
        "ls": {
            "python": {
                "analysis": {
                    "useLibraryCodeForTypes": True,
                    "typeCheckingMode": "basic",  # ["off", "basic", "strict"]
                    "logLevel": "Infomation",
                },
                "pythonPath": "/home/jizhou/venv/bin/python",
            }
        }
    }
```

For ycm lsp and jedi-language-server, hover doesn't work too. But it can't solve virtualenv.
global_extra_conf.py

```py
def Settings(**kwargs):
    return {
        "ls": {
            "diagnostic": {"enable": True},
            "hover": {"enable": True},
            "workspace": {
                "environmentPath": "~/venv/bin/python"
            },
        }
    }
```

For syntastics with pylint, syntastics plugin works well but performance and function problem usually appear. It can't check on insert mode exist. And if turn on check on open, it will slow down vim's starting up.

**My question is**:

Is there any way to make ycm not only complete the modules of the virtual environment, but also quickly check for errors like lsp without reducing the performance of vim, and at the same time ensure the normal operation of the hover function?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Now what is your question?

Comment: @Friedrich sorry for my first time. I've complete my question

Comment: Knowing that a linter has to be available in virtualenv, I chose to use syntastic and flake8 in virtualenv together with the built-in jedi ycm. Even yet, there is still no support for the insert mode check.

Comment: If this is the answer you found, please scroll all the way down, paste your answer in the textbox and click "Post Your Answer". SO encourages self-answers.

Comment: Another thing, note that Syntastic was discontinued a while ago. Its creators suggest to give [ALE](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) a try. So far, I am not disappointed, YMMV.

Comment: @Friedrich I think ALE has too much features duplicated with ycm. Thank you for your advise and I may choose ALE if I get tired of syntastic.

Answer (score 0):

At present, my solution is checking with syntastic with flake8 in virtualenv and completing with built-in Jedi. Note that a Python linter must be available in virtualenv, which means the package globally installed by pacman is **invalid**.

My view of syntastic is:

```
...
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 0   " avoid slow on start up
let g:syntastic_python_checkers = ['flake8']
let g:syntastic_python_flake8_exec = "$HOME/venv/bin/flake8"
let g:syntastic_python_flake8_args = "--max-line-length=132"

let g:syntastic_cursor_column = 0 " disable to speed up navigation significantly
...
```

Moreover, I found that syntastic will report an error when close a split buffer. I forked and fixed this bug by add a `silent`, which can be install by

```
Plug 'ieeyaY/syntastic', {'branch': 'ieeyaFix'}
```